# A technically correct valentines

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to formulate a technically correct valentine's day message, but I don't quite know enough topology to phrase this right. Pointers would be appreciated, or an alternative example (without a comma between "M" and "e"). I'm using (or trying to use) the example from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Completion.html .

---

Theoretical valentines statement:

> Let $M$ be the set $\mathbb{Q}$, and $e$ the distance metric defined by (not sure here). Note that $M$ contains a Cauchy Sequence which does not converge, e.g., $1.4, 1.41, 1.414, ...$ because $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$. Let $u = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Then $u$ completes $(M, e)$.

---

Back to the question.

Does $u$ actually complete $(M, e)$? Isn't that supposed to be given by a larger space $(X, e)$?

Comment: I think you want to let $u=\mathbb{R}$, and $e(x,y)=|x-y|$.  Because currently what you have is incorrect since $\mathbb{Q} \not\subseteq \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: When you say "technically correct" what are you going for exactly? I think the statement is essentially true, i.e., I think it is pretty clear what you mean and that the thing you mean is true, i.e., that $(M,e)$ isn't complete, and that there's a thing made of both $u$ and $(M,e)$ that is complete. However, "this set completes that set," in your sense, is not a standard usage as far as I'm aware. If by "completes" you mean "is the completion of," then you have to take $u$ to be $\mathbb{R}$, though this kills the romance a little b/c I know you want $u$ and $(M,e)$ to be complements...

Comment: ...making up a complete whole rather than having $(M,e)$ be embedded in $u$.